# What is the difference b/w sshd_config and sshd command?

Tags: unix, redhat, sshd

I changed my `sshd_config` file to set strictmodes to no and then restarted the `sshd` service.
However, I am getting two different outputs as shown below.

---

```
root@localhost httpd]# service sshd stop
Stopping sshd:                                             [  OK  ]
[root@localhost httpd]# service sshd start
Starting sshd:                                             [  OK  ]
[root@localhost httpd]# sudo cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep StrictModes
#StrictModes no
[root@localhost httpd]# sshd -T | grep strictmodes
strictmodes yes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most of the configuration files have `#` as a comment and therefore the options behind it are not used and therefore your server is using its defaults, which is `yes`. Change the line in your `sshd_config` to

```
StrictModes no
```

and restart the service. It will be applied.